# Run Selenium or equivalent framework on a production server

Tags: javascript, php, curl, selenium

I am PHP newbie. I am writing a cURL script that needs to interact with Javascript. I have looked for ways to run Javascript and several forums have recomended using Selenium. I've looked at some Selenium tutorials and I'm a bit hesitant because Selenium seems to require that the host machine runs a browser and has JRE installed.

Is there an alternative way to capture Javascript output in PHP?

An example would be to open a site like offgamers.com. This page calls JS to set a cookie, then it displays the index page. I want to get the contents of index.php page in a PHP variable.

```
$ch = curl_init();

target = "http://www.offgamers.com/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/), [zombiejs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)

Comment: Explain us, what are you trying to accomplish...provide an example pls

Comment: @RobertRozas: I've revised my question

Comment: Try [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver) with online webdriver service like [testingbot](http://testingbot.com) or setup your own [webdriver grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) in another server.